# Jasmine: test extended angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm extending ui-bootstrap-carousel. In order for my test to work, the original carousel directive must execute. This is working within the application (via myDirective.priority: -1). However, it appears the original directive is not being run in my test.

```
// console.log( iElement ) output:
{0: <div data-carousel="" data-interval="interval" class="ng-scope"></div>, length: 1}
```

In my test I set it up with ui-bootstrap-carousel included like so:

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive: Carousel', function () {

  beforeEach(module('myApp','ui.bootstrap.carousel'));
```

I can't find any documentation on testing multiple directives or anything with a dependency on a directive.

I've ensured that karma.config has the correct path to ui.bootstrap.carousel, and Karma doesn't spit out any errors except that my test has failed (because bootstrap carousel didn't execute).

Comment: I don't understand your 1st code snippet. Can you please reformat or add more info?

Comment: @Sylvain, the first snippet is the output when I log the template after it's been $compiled(), aka _iElement_.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ui-bootstrap-carousel but I have unit tested directives that depend on other directives. What do you mean exactly by *I'm **extending** ui-bootstrap-carousel*? Are you replacing its controller or the directive itself? Can you provide your directive definition?

Comment: @Sylvain [AngularJS: Extending Directives, stacking](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives#wiki-stacking-directives)

Comment: Add `console.log('name')` at this line: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L529. If you don't see your directive name printed twice (once for angular-ui's directive and once for yours), then the problem is with loading the angular-ui module itself.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: sort of: I think I'm not supposed to do that, but should instead mock the output of the other directive.